# Flutter - Generate .ipa file

Tags: ios, flutter, ipa

The official Flutter documentations says that the following command produces both ipa and xcarchive files.

> flutter build ipa

From the Flutter documentation [to generate ipa](https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/ios#create-an-app-bundle)

> Run flutter build ipa to produce an Xcode build archive (.xcarchive
> file) in your project’s build/ios/archive/ directory and an App Store
> app bundle (.ipa file) in build/ios/ipa.

However, the command is generating only .xcarchive file. How can we generate the .ipa file? Looks like we can generate from Xcode Export but trying to look for a command line command to generate .ipa file to integrate into CI/CD solution.

Comment: i think you can get the ipa by archiving it in xcode then the file from xcode try go to **xcode->preferences->Go To Locations->below select/Click Archives arrow below** i bet you can see files extension .xcarchive

Answer (score 0):

You can generate .ipa file for distribution using Xcode via following steps

1.Open iOS folder of your project in Xcode

2. then **Product -> Archive**
   It once this is complete open up the Organiser and click the latest version.

[image: organizer]

3.Now click on Distribute App This will open list of method for export. Select the export method as per your requirement **(In your case i think you want to distribute app for testing)** so select Development option and click on Next button.

[image]

4.Now it will ask for app thining and re-signed for development distribution select Automatically managing signing it take some  time to generate .ipa file after that you can export .ipa file in your desire location.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I was looking for a more automated way with a command line command.

Answer (score 0):

When you run `flutter build ipa`, it generates a `Runner.xcarchive` and an IPA.

Output of `flutter build`:

```bash
Xcode archive done.                                         65.6s
Built /Users/user/repos/app_name/build/ios/archive/Runner.xcarchive.
Building App Store IPA...                                          64.5s
Built IPA to /Users/user/repos/app_name/build/ios/ipa.
```

The generated file is called `app_name.ipa`.

Answer (score 0):

Create IPA and specify how the IPA will be distributed.

`flutter build ipa --export-method development`